# Counting solutions to mixed integer linear programs

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

Say I have a mixed integer linear program in variables $x \in \mathbb{Z}^a, y \in \mathbb{Z}^b, z \in \mathbb{R}^c$ together with linear constraints on $(x,y,z)$.  I want to count the number of values of $x \in \mathbb{Z}^a$ s.t. a solution $(x,y,z)$ exists.

Is there existing software to solve problems of this type?  There are lots of MILP solvers (mixed integer linear programming), but I don't know of any that solve the counting version of the problem rather than the decision or search problems.

Comment: I once asked something similar at Operations Research SE, [Using CPLEX "solution pool" to count feasible points](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/167/using-cplex-solution-pool-to-count-feasible-points).  A Comment on one Answer pointed me to [SCIP's count command](https://www.scipopt.org/doc-6.0.1/html/COUNTER.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found after some more searching:

[LattE](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Elatte/software.php) counts lattice points within rational polytopes via Barvinok's algorithm, which computes the rational multivariate generating function of the lattice points in a region (and then plugs in $x = 1$ to get the count).  This works because the generating functions can be additively combined over different pieces of the polytope (at vertices and faces).  A paper describing the software is

[De Loera et al., Effective lattice point counting in rational convex polytopes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717104000422)

Sage appears to [use LattE as a dependency](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/base_QQ.html), so that's an easy way to access it.

Answer (score 3):

A brute force way to do this with a conventional MILP solver is to find an optimal integer solution, add a cut to separate that integer solution from the other feasible integer solutions, reoptimize, and repeat until you run out of integer solutions.  For problems with a very small number of integer solutions and lots of continuous variables, this can work well, but it can also be very slow if there are many integer solutions.

Finding a separating cut is easy for problems with binary variables, but it becomes a problem specific challenge in general.

Comment: Yes, this works, but is (more than) exponential in the number of solutions, while LattE is closer to exponential in the number of dimensions.